# Is rewording to remove redundant instances of a single word worth an edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

There's [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167875/75000) about Obi-wan's <s>fight</s> *confrontation* with General Grievous during EpIII. Currently, the word 'fight' is used five times, and 'fought' is used twice (once in the title). The question itself isn't difficult to read or understand, but personally, I think it would **look nicer** if parts were reworded to remove the extra instances. If not both, then at least for 'fight'.

Would making this edit, while keeping the original question intact, be a worthwhile and valid one?

If yes, would this apply to answers as well?

---

### **Immediate update**

The question has been edited by [@William Jackson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4985/william-jackson), and is completely reworked, including removing a few of the 'fight's. But my original question still stands.

**If a post contains the same word in excess but is otherwise readable, is removing the extra uses an acceptable edit?**

Comment: Meh, it's not important either way IMO

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ is somewhat conflicted, but the general principle is that **making lots of these edits is discouraged. Making a *single* edit of this sort is probably ok.**

> **[Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)** - try to make the post
> significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you
> observe.

and

> [When should I approve?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing)
>
> Whenever a change improves a topic in clarity, correctness, or
> conciseness it should be approved.
>
> **Even small improvements add up over time, so don't reject "trivial"
> changes that are still improvements.**

Answer (score 2):

**Edits for objective *improvements* are fine.**

If you're fixing someone's spelling or grammar or punctuation or capitalisation, or improving the layout or formatting of their post, that's fine (with the [usual caveats](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) about not making loads of trivial edits).

**Edits for *stylistic* changes usually aren't.**

Unless you can make a very good argument that your style is objectively better than theirs, don't go around changing the style of people's posts. For instance, editing American to British English, or removing all the apostrophes (changing "isn't" to "is not" and so on), is *not* a good edit.

---

We could probably sit here all day arguing about whether using synonyms is better than repeating the same word over and over again. Excessive repetition certainly makes for bad writing, but so does excessive use of synonyms. I'm sure the good folks at [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com) or [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com) could give you a good debate on that topic. I'm not going to judge one way or the other, but as a general rule, the question you should be asking is: **"am I objectively improving the post, or just making it something *I* like better?"**